# Constructing templated tuple types

Tags: c++, templates, tuples, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am trying to write a function like this

```
template<
        bool b, RT = std::conditional_t<b,
               std::tuple<int, int, int, int>,
               std::tuple<int, int, int, int, double, double, double, double>
        >
RT function()
{
    int i1, i2, i3, i4;

    if constexpr(b)
    {
        double i5, i6, i7, i8;
        return { i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8 };
    }
    else
    {
        return { i1, i2, i3, i4 };
    }
}
```

Is there a way to create a templated typedef for the tuple so that I can simplify the above function

```
template<typename T, int N>
using tuple_t = std::tuple<T, T, ... N1 times>

template<typename T1, int N1, typename T2, int N2>
using tuple_t = std::tuple<T1, T1, ... N1 times, T2, T2, ... N2 times>
```

Comment: Why not just do something like `using some_name = std::tuple<int, int, int, int>; using another_name = std::tuple<int, int, int, int, double, double, double, double>;`?

Comment: @NathanOliver this is just a representative example. I have use cases with different combinations of `T1`, `T2`, `N1`, `N2` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use return type deduction and replace the aggregate initialization with a call to `make_tuple`:

```
template<bool b>
auto function()
{
    int i1, i2, i3, i4;

    if constexpr(b)
    {
        double i5, i6, i7, i8;
        return std::make_tuple(i1, i2, i3, i4, i5, i6, i7, i8);
    }
    else
    {
        return std::make_tuple(i1, i2, i3, i4);
    }
}
```

If you still need the return type you can simply make a trait:

```
template <bool b>
using return_t = decltype(function<b>());
```

Comment: That's a really nice and simple solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Is too late to play?

To respond to your generic question

> Is there a way to create a templated typedef for the tuple so that I can simplify the above function
>
> ```
> template<typename T, int N>
> using tuple_t = std::tuple<T, T, ... N1 times>
>
> template<typename T1, int N1, typename T2, int N2>
> using tuple_t = std::tuple<T1, T1, ... N1 times, T2, T2, ... N2 times>
> ```

I propose the following, full and compilable, C++14 example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>

template <typename T, std::size_t>
using get_type = T;

template <typename T, std::size_t ... Is>
constexpr std::tuple<get_type<T, Is>...>
   get_tuple_t (std::index_sequence<Is...>);

template <typename T, std::size_t N>
using tuple_t_1 = decltype(get_tuple_t<T>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{}));

template <typename T1, std::size_t N1, typename T2, std::size_t N2>
using tuple_t_2 = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
      std::declval<tuple_t_1<T1, N1>>(),
      std::declval<tuple_t_1<T2, N2>>()));

int main ()
 {
   using t1a = tuple_t_1<int, 4u>;
   using t1b = std::tuple<int, int, int, int>;
   using t2a = tuple_t_2<int, 4u, double, 4u>;
   using t2b = std::tuple<int, int, int, int, double, double, double, double>;

   static_assert( std::is_same<t1a, t1b>::value, "!" );
   static_assert( std::is_same<t2a, t2b>::value, "!" );
 }
```

Comment: very cool solution, I didn't know about `std::index_sequence`

Comment: @Bilentor - unfortunately `std::make_index_sequence` and `std::index_sequence` are available only starting from C++14